# Custom header on parent stack navigator with react-navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have an app using `react-navigation` which has basically this structure:

StackNavigator -> BottomTabBarNavigator -> (each tab) StackNavigator

I am trying to add a global button component, it lived on the TabBar, but there are sibling views that would hide it when they are shown. So, ultimately the best place to put it would be on the parent StackNavigator, however, when I try to put the custom header on the `navigationOptions` of the parent StackNavigator, I get the error

`Unexpected token, expected "</>/<=/>="`

And it points to the `{` in `header: props => <ConversationBuble {...props} />` on the navigationOptions object. Which I dont understand, as I am able to do this on the child most StackNavigator. Can anyone help me understand what the problem is here and why I am unable to inject the custom header at the parent level?

Comment: Are you imported react in parent StackNavigator? This line `import React from 'react'`

Comment: @AlexanderVidaurreArroyo Importing react doesnt make a difference in terms of the error. I wasn't, but I added it without any change.

Comment: My code editor (vs code) don't let me use jsx syntax without import React.  I thought it would be the problem

Comment: Try this `props => (<ConversationBuble {...props} />)`. Wrap jsx with parentheses

Comment: @AlexanderVidaurreArroyo I have tried that, and every other permutation of it I can think of. Simply doesnt work. However, the very same syntax lets me modify the header at the child level. So, `Stack` -> `TabBar` -> `Stack (works here)` but I need it at the global level.